# JQuery/JavaScript: Iterate through form fields, perform calculation, then submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Right now my code is very "hard-coded" and repetitive.  I'd like to know if there is a cleaner way to do the following.  Ideally, I want to iterate through my forms fields with a loop and calculate the results with one statement, but I'm struggling to figure out how best to do so.

**Summary:**  I have ten form fields, each with a distinct decimal value that a user may or may not supply.  When the user hits submit, it should add the value in the input field with a value being displayed on the current HTML page, then insert into the DB.

First, I grab that value from the form input field and convert it into a number with two decimal places.  I then grab the current total from the HTML and add the two numbers together.  After that I inject that total back into the form input field so that it can be stored in `$_POST` and inserted into a database.

How can I make my code more DRY (ie, Don't Repeat Yourself)? Below are just two examples but they are exactly the same except for the element calls:

```
var subtotal = Number($("#housing").val());
subtotal = (subtotal).toFixed(2);
var currentTotal = $('#output-housing').html().replace("$", "");
var total = Number(subtotal) + Number(currentTotal);
$('#housing').val(total);

var subtotal = Number($("#utilities").val());
subtotal = (subtotal).toFixed(2);
var currentTotal = $('#output-utilities').html().replace("$", "");
var total = Number(subtotal) + Number(currentTotal);
$('#utilities').val(total);
```

I would like to iterate through my input fields like so, but I'm trying to figure out how I could display the logic inside:

```
var input = $('.form-expenses :input');
input.each(function() {
    // Insert switch statement here??  Some other construct??
});
```

**HTML:** (Uses Bootstrap 3 classes)

FORM:

```
<form class="form-expenses form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="/profile/update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="housing" class="control-label col-sm-3">Housing</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="housing" id="housing" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="utilities" class="control-label col-sm-3">Utilities</label>
        <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-sm-9"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="utilities" id="utilities" />
        </div>
    </div>
...
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="update-expenses" type="submit"> Update</button>

</form>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<tr>
  <td>Housing</td>
  <td id="output-housing">$<?php echo $total['housing']?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Utilities</td>
  <td id="output-utilities">$<?php echo $total['utilities']?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What's the relevant html we're working with?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'll add that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Assumes the same prefixing relationship of output/input ID's

```
$(function() {
  $('form.form-expenses').submit(function() {
    updateValues();
    return false/* prevent submit for demo only*/
  })
})

function updateValues(){
  $('.form-expenses :input').not('#update-expenses').each(function(){
    var $input=$(this), inputId=this.id;
    var curr=$('#output-'+inputId).text().replace("$", "");
    $input.val(function(i,val){
      return (1*(val ||0) + 1*curr).toFixed(2);
    })
  });
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FMzdMSDoRWjlciIIzEkb?p=preview)**</kbd>

From a UI perspective, this seems very counter intuitive to change values that user just input.

To create ajax data object instead of updating the display values:

```
function getAjaxData(){
  var ajaxData={}
  $('.form-expenses :input').not('#update-expenses').each(function(){
    var $input=$(this), inputId=this.id;
    var curr=$('#output-'+inputId).text().replace("$", "");
    ajaxData[this.name] =(1*(val ||0) + 1*curr).toFixed(2);
  });
  return ajaxData
}

/* in submit handler*/

$.post('path/to/server', getAjaxData(), function(response){/*do something with reponse*/})
```

Comment: Related to your last comment.  I agree, what I did is on submit I added `$('.form-expenses :input').val('');` to immediately hide the value so that the user doesn't see.  To the user, it appears as if they input a value and it gets added in to the HTML.  However, if you have a better idea, let me know.

Comment: if submitting via ajax I would leave form alone...and just send the calculated data. Not sure how your full UI works...but have to consider any post problems that might occur (lost connection for example)

Comment: Right now I use ajax to send the data via the form and then use javascript to immediately display it.  Is there some other way that I can send the data to the DB besides the form inputs?  Maybe do the calculation inside of the jQuery `$.ajax()` method itself?

Comment: very easy to create data object to send instead...I just updated answer

Answer (score 1):

> "if I allow a user to add/remove fields, then this could get a bit sticky"

In that case, give your fields a class name. As long as that exists on added fields, they will all be calculated.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control calculate-me" name="housing" id="housing" />
```

And iterate though all, using their ids as a reference

```
$(".calculate-me").each(function(){
    var ref=this.id;
    var subtotal = Number($("#" + ref).val());
    subtotal = (subtotal).toFixed(2);
    var currentTotal = $('#output-' + ref).html().replace("$", "");
    var total = Number(subtotal) + Number(currentTotal);
    $('#' + ref).val(total);
});
```

Comment: I like this way because it really is simple.  However, I still need to hard code the refs array.  Honestly, my fields won't change that often so not too big of a deal, but if I allow a user to add/remove fields, then this could get a bit sticky...